# Is it possible to open a gps in webapp

Tags: html, gps

Could I use the anchor tag to send an address to my phones gps and go from there?
Like when you use the anchor tag to tell you phone it is a tel number.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much everything you'd need to do something like this, can be done with this block of code:

```
<p>Location:<br />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script><div style="overflow:hidden;height:300px;width:450px;">
    <div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:300px;width:450px;"></div>
    <style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style><a class="google-map-code" href="" id="get-map-data"></a></div>    

<script type="text/javascript"> function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:14,center:new google.maps.LatLng(40.26489,-74.533312),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.26489,-74.533312)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"<b>Lawton's Service Company, Inc</b><br/>400 Mercer St<br /> Hightstown, NJ 08520" });google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script><br />
        <div style="width:450px;text-align:center;">
            <form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="_blank">

                <input type="hidden" name="saddr" id="address" />
                <input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="400 Mercer St, Hightstown, NJ 08520" />
                <input type="submit" value="Get Directions" class="menubarBut" style="height: 40px;width:200px" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

You can provide your own address information and so on.  And clicking the button on a mobile device will prompt the user to use Maps, GPS, or anything else they have installed to make use of it.

Comment: Awesome! I will implement it now and get back.

Comment: Hmm it seems to be taking me to a website(google) where it will post directions from there. No option to leave webapp and open gps.

Comment: It will on a mobile device.  I've tested that on all manner of iOS and Android devices.  It obviously won't do that on a desktop, unless you happen to have a GPS on it.  It will however, identify your location.  In any case, I don't think you can launch a specific app (gps) on any device, because there is no way of telling what app is there to launch.  That's why the device makes suggestions.

Comment: yeah I tested it on my iPhone 5s.
I will try it again lol. One sec